# Chrome headless (command line): wait until screenshot is finished

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I am running chrome headless via cmd (Windows):

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1280,768 --screenshot="path\to\file.png" "path\to\index.html?param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

The image is generated as expected.

The problem is that the process seems to run in the background, because:

1. The command line is finished almost instantly
2. The png is created some seconds later

Is there a way to avoid #1 and let the cmd finish when the png is finally saved?

The reason is that I want to chain another operation after that, and this second operation expects the png to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect solution by any means, but you could try waiting a specified number of seconds before executing the second command.  This could look like:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --window-size=1280,768 --screenshot="path\to\file.png" "path\to\index.html?param1=value1&param2=value2" && timeout <# of seconds you want to wait> && <your second command>
```

This would not start the second command directly after the first finished, but you could still atleast get it to work in one line.